# Converting character string to a vector

Tags: r

Is it possible to convert, in R, a character string input into a vector output from a user made function?

Something along the lines of:

```
 userfcn<-function("06/23/1298")
```

with a desired output of vector

```
06 23 1298
```

I tried using the strsplit() function, but I am not trying to split the character string. I would like the output to be a vector of just 06 23 1289. Using the strsplit() would still produce the backslashes in the output.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `strsplit("06/23/1298", "/")[[1]]`

Comment: Thank you, I am new to R and appreciate the help! Is there a way I can assign this new output of "06" "23" "1298" to a new variable as well?

Comment: just assign it: `newvar  <-  strsplit("06/23/1298", "/")[[1]]`